# Sending Mail with Attachment only works in GMail

Tags: android, email, attachment

I am trying to send a mail with an attachment from my Galaxy Note 3 tablet. My code to send the mail looks like this:

```
public static void sendMail(Context context, String rc, String subject, String message, File file, String type) {
    Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { rc });
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    email.putExtra("android.intent.extra.MIME_TYPES", type);
//      email.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail");
    email.setClassName("com.android.email", "com.android.email.activity.MessageCompose");
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    context.startActivity(email);
}
```

The file is saved to the external sdcard. If i use the Gmail app, the attachment is attached and I can send my mail. If I use the stock email app from android, the attachment is not attached and I have no idea why.

Does anybody know why this is happening? I found a lot of questions, how to attach a file to an email and they nearly all use this way of attaching the file. So why it only works for the gmail app?

Answer (score 3):

i had similar problems before, but with this code i could send an email with a csv file as attachment, using "myMail" as client.

```
 Uri exportFile = null;
 exportFile = Uri.fromFile(file);
 Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

 emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "testSubject");
 emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, exportFile);
 String aEmailList[] = { "test@test.org" };
 emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, aEmailList);
 emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
 emailIntent.putExtra(
     Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
     emailText
     );       
 startActivityForResult(emailIntent, REQUESTCODE_SENTEMAIL);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out... you have to use the `setType()` method of the email Intent to set the typ of the mail. Then, the stock mail app recognizes the attachment.

Comment: What was the type you ended up setting? "image/*"?

Comment: Dude...what was the type?